# Как использовать openapi?

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь понять openapi и как его использовать с django, но в интернете попадаются только примеры и объяснения самого api(кода, элементов и т.д.). Допустим, у меня есть документ с кодом openapi. Что значит отрендерить openapi документ? И как мне его использовать в своем проекте django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI – это спецификация протоколов клиент-серверного взаимодействия. Инструменты таких спецификами позволяют из описания протокола в определённом формате генерировать код для клиентских и серверных сторон на любом нужном языке. Такая автоматизация и единая точка зависимости позволяет более быстро и точно реализовывать новые версии протоколов для множества языков и фреймворков.

Вот реализации OpenAPI на Питоне:

- PySwagger, [GitHub](https://github.com/pyopenapi/pyswagger)
- OpenAPI-Core, [GitHub](https://github.com/p1c2u/openapi-core), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/openapi-core/)

Более полный список инструментов:

- https://openapi.tools

Если Вы используете OpenAPI для генерации клиентского кода, то с Джанго и любыми другими используемыми в проекте технологиями это никак не связано. Если для серверного, то по всей видимости, существующие инструменты не работают с Django и DRF, но поддерживают фреймворки Flask и Tornado.

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов использовать OpenAPI в связке с Django Rest Framework - это реализовать серверную часть и сгенерировать по ней документацию для клиента. Это существенно удобнее и быстрее, чем потом описывать её вручную. Вот примеры библиотек позволяющие это сделать:

https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/  *deprecated (2019-06-04)*

https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg